# Admin Login Issue 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4, admin-login

Hello i'm getting an issue after moving my live 2.4.4 website (example.com) into a staging subdomain (testing.example.com)
As you can see in screen shot i have broken CSS in admin login and also not working
but i'm sure that username/password are correct
https://ibb.co/4PMJ10c

Also frontend works fine i have this issue only for backend

1. I already cleared cache **/var/cache** and **/var/page_cache** by FTP and also from composer with
   **chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/** (frontend) and
   **rm -rf var/cache/*** and **var/page_cache/*** (backend)
2. I also run some CSS fixing but nothing
   **sudo php bin/magento s:s:d --area adminhtml -f**
   and **sudo php bin/magento s:s:d en_AU -f**

Any other suggestion or check that i can do?
Thanks

Comment: Try viewing the page source. What lanuage is it trying to load?

Comment: Ok i can see this in page source /static/version1654869836/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_AU'

Comment: Ssh into your server and check if pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_AU exist and contain the files.

Comment: Yes i can confirm

Comment: If the physical files are there then it seems to be more of a server issue check your .htaccess file and files permission

Comment: I fixed folder and files permission: https://ibb.co/kmVd9fK since i still have the error mayve i need to check the htaccess. What in particular?

Comment: I think problem is CSP but i don't know how can i fix it.. https://ibb.co/JRNpms8

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this commands one's.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: now it's better! i can login and see dashboard. However if i try to click on any item menù doesn't work.. https://ibb.co/TqTFJ2W

Comment: Try to run the compilation commands one's. And Try to first disable third party extension one by one and check if any issues with that one.

Comment: I think problem is CSP but i don't know how can i fix it.. https://ibb.co/JRNpms8